# Wordpress Custom Widget renders "1" on output

Tags: wordpress, widget

my Wordpress Custom Widget renders behind the output from the display() method a "1". I think it's because the echo is evaluated.

```
public function widget($args, $instance) {
    echo 'this is my output';
}
```

My output is the following

```
this is my output1
```

Anyone have a solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to create a Wordpress widget or did you just name your function "widget"?

Comment: Yes, this is a Wordpress widget. Why do you ask?

Comment: Are you registering it with the widgets_init hook? 
E.g. `add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
 register_widget( 'My_Widget' );
});`

Comment: Yes, it works on the right way. The only problem is the output of the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add `die;` ?

**For example :**

```
public function widget($args, $instance) {
    echo 'this is my output';
    die;
}
```

Comment: When I do this the "1" is not rendered anymore. So the output will come from something behind this method.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. If you use Timber to integrate twig as template engine into Wordpress, follow the documentation how to integrate widgets into the twig templates (https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/sidebar#method-3-dynamic) :)